# Can't type between the f's in "bff" in some Chrome text fields

Tags: google-chrome

In some text fields in Chrome, I can't edit between two consecutive lowercase letter F's. For instance, on the search box for Logz.io this happens and on my company's backend which uses bootstrap 3.

So far I haven't been able to figure out what the commonality is. I had a colleague confirm it happens on his computer as well. This seems to be a really strange bug. What could be the cause of it?

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me (on the given site). What language settings do you use? In some languages, ff could be a special char, like ‘ll’ or ‘rr’ in spanish [those are single characters in spanish]

Comment: I'm using US English. My colleague is using the same. Both of us on MacOS Sierra and Chrome 63.0.3239.132. Maybe we both have some Chrome extension in common that's doing it.

Comment: Check something isn't replacing the 2 f's ff with a ligature, ﬀ - they may look the same but they are different characters; the ligature is a single character. Copy/paste your double f & my ligature into the Keyboard,Emoji, Symbol viewer to test [system prefs/keyboard/keyboard to enable it in the menu bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What could be the cause of it?**

It could be an ﬀ [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) such as [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF' (U+FB00)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb00/index.htm)

It is conceivable that a typed ff is replaced with ﬀ by an autocorrect feature or smart-typography feature.

[image: Typography selection dialog]

CSS

```
/* Enable Ligatures ================ */
letter-spacing: 0;
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1";
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga";
-ms-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
-o-font-feature-settings: "liga";
font-feature-settings: "liga";
```

Comment: The moment I copy it out of the field in question where it appears to be a ligature FF, and paste into the characters search field on my Mac, it turns into a regular double f.